# jq to remove one of the duplicated objects

Tags: json, linux, jq

I have a json file like this:

```
{"caller_id":"123321","cust_name":"abc"}
{"caller_id":"123443","cust_name":"def"}
{"caller_id":"123321","cust_name":"abc"}
{"caller_id":"234432","cust_name":"ghi"}
{"caller_id":"123321","cust_name":"abc"}
....
```

I tried:

```
jq -s 'unique_by(.field1)'
```

but this will remove all the duplicated items, I,m looking to keep just one of the duplicated items, to get the file like this:

```
{"caller_id":"123321","cust_name":"abc"}
{"caller_id":"123443","cust_name":"def"}
{"caller_id":"234432","cust_name":"ghi"}
....
```

Comment: But there is no `field1` in any of those objects... everything will be removed. You need to key in a field that actually exists. e.g., `jq -cs 'unique_by(.cust_name)[]' input.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `field1`, I doubt you are getting anything in the output, since there is no key/field with the given name. If you simply change your command to `jq -s 'unique_by(.caller_id)'` it will give you desired result containing unique & sorted objects based on `caller_id` key. It will ensure in result you have atleast & atmost one object for each `caller_id`.

NOTE: Same as what @Jeff Mercado has explained in the comments.

Comment: You are right, I meant  .caller_id but I used field1 as example. I tried jq -s 'unique_by(.caller_id)' and it is ok, may I ask if I can keep the item where cust_name !="" ? TIA

Comment: I am little confused now, If you can clarify by modifying your question with input json and expected output json, I will update my answer with desired solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just removed the lines where "cust_name":"" using vi, and it is OK now

Comment: @AmithKumar Quite late here but your answer `jq -cs 'unique_by(.cust_name)[]' input.json` and @Jeff Mercado in the comments has  `jq -cs 'unique_by(.caller_id)' input.json` . One has a `[]` and one doesnt. Whats the difference?

Comment: `[]` effects how the output will look like. `[]` operator extracts the elements of the input array. So here, its works as a second operation on the output of `unique_by` operation. Its equivalent to saying:
`jq -s 'unique_by(.caller_id)' inputJsonObjects.txt | jq '.[]'`

Answer (score 1):

If the file consists of a sequence (stream) of JSON objects, then a very simple way to produce a stream of the distinct objects would be to use the invocation:

```
jq -s `unique[]`
```

A similar alternative would be:

```
jq -n `[inputs] | unique[]`
```

For large files, however, the above will probably be too inefficient, both with respect to RAM and run-time. Note that both `unique` and `unique_by` entail a sort.

A far better alternative would be to take advantage of the fact that the input is a stream, and to avoid the built-in `unique` and `unique_by` filters.  This can be done with the assistance of the following filters, which are not yet built-in but likely to become so:

```
# emit a dictionary
def set(s): reduce s as $x ({}; .[$x | (type[0:1] + tostring)] = $x);

# distinct entities in the stream s
def distinct(s): set(s)[];
```

We now have only to add:

```
distinct(inputs)
```

to achieve the objective, provided jq is invoked with the -n command-line option.

This approach will also preserve the original ordering.

### If the input is an array ...

If the input is an array, then using `distinct` as defined above still has the advantage of not requiring a sort.  For arrays that are too large to fit comfortably in memory, it would be advisable to use jq's streaming parser to create a stream.

One possibility would be to proceed in two steps (`jq --stream .... | jq -n ...`), but it might be better to do everything in one step (`jq -cn --stream ...`), using the following "main" program:

```
distinct(fromstream(inputs 
                    | (.[0] |= .[1:] )
                    | select(. != [[]])))
```